# How to solve an error when using mutate()

Tags: r, error-handling, dplyr

Can anyone tell me how to deal with the following error message when using mutate() in R?

> Error: Column `CO` must be length 3 (the group size) or one, not 3033

Below is my code:

```
newdata <- mydata %>% mutate(CO=rowMeans(mydata[,25:30],na.rm = TRUE))
```

note: `mydata` is a dataset that includes 3033 individuals embedded in 813 groups; each group has 3 to 8 individual members. Column 25 to 30 contains 6 variables of which the mean value should be calculated.

Any idea would be highly appreciated!!

Comment: You are trying to fit all 3033 row means into each group of 3 - 8 members. You could either use tidyselect methods or temporarily ungroup, then run your mutate, then regroup (since rowMeans is calculated rowwise, groups are irrelevant to the answers it gives)

Comment: Thank you, @AllanCameron! I end up trying temporarily ungroup and it worked!